# AWS S3 make public via ACL disabled?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to make my file public through AWS management console, I have already turned off the bucket block public access as below.

[image]

But when I go to the file and try to make the file public, the option is disabled

[image]

I followed the official instruction on AWS, but apparently, it had some new updates on this option.

https://aws.amazon.com/tw/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/read-access-objects-s3-bucket/

Am I missing anything or there are some settings I did'nt do ?

Comment: Note that the Block Public Access setting can be applied at both the account and bucket level. Check both are disabled. Also, there are 4 lower-level settings (you've only shown the high-level setting) so be sure they are set appropriately.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Probably the bucket has ACLs disabled.

Since [November 2021](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/11/amazon-s3-object-ownership-simplify-access-management-data-s3/), you can disable access control lists (ACLs). Using ACLs is not recommended except in unusual circumstances where you need to control access for each object individually. Instead you should grant permissions using the bucket policy.

Anyway, if you need to use ACLs then to enable it go to Permissions tab and change the Object Ownership option:

[image: Object Ownership]

Comment: Thank you ! so is it not a good practice to use ACL directly? If it is, why?  I am quite new to AWS haha

Comment: AWS recommends the use of bucket policies over ACLs because it simplyfies access management (using ACL grants permissions on per object basis).
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/about-object-ownership.html
For other cloud providers the concept is applied e.g. Google Cloud. 
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists

Comment: Just an update for this answer. Here's the step to enable by ACL: 1. Go to the bucket 2. Go to Permissions 3. Go to Object Ownership section 4. Click Edit 5. Select ACL enabled 6. Change object ownership to Object writer. 7. Click "I acknowledge .." 8. Save changes

Answer (score 9):

You can try to edit the bucket policy as step 2 of this [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteAccessPermissionsReqd.html).

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::Bucket-Name/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This reading may also helps: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-photos-view.html

Comment: If you do this, all the files in your bucket will be made public.